# Find all methods which depend on third-party library

Tags: .net, decompiling, ilspy

I use ILSpy to explore assemblies. Now I have a task to find all methods in the investigated assembly which depend on a third-party assembly. In other words, I want to know what methods in my assembly call methods in third-party assembly. Is it possible somehow using ILSpy or another software?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a tool that automates the depends on analysis.

If the third party assembly is small enough you could load it and the investigated assembly and use the Find Usages feature of JustDecompile on all the types in the assembly and start from there. The investigated assembly will have to be of manageable size too.

You could also automate it but you'll have to write some code to do that. Both JustDecompile and ILSpy engines are open source. You can create a plugin that does that.

Last but not least you can upvote this - https://justdecompile.uservoice.com/forums/113277-justdecompile-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1772437-provide-depends-on-analysis so that this feature gets higher on the backlog of JustDecompile.